# Pass data between class components through link in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass data from one component to another component by using state of link. But when i get on target component it says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')". Here is my code

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
class Header extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>                
            <header className="mb-3">
            <Link to={{
                        pathname:'/zone',
                        state:'testing'
                        }}  className="btn icon icon-left btn-primary" > click me</Link>
            </header>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Header
```

Here is the target component

```
import React from "react";
class Zones extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount() {      
        console.log(this.props.location.state);            
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>                
            <h1>Zones</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Zones
```

Please let me know where i am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing an Object instead of a String in the state property?
e.g.

```
<Link to={{
        pathname:'/zone',
        state: { test: 'testing' }
      }}
      className="btn icon icon-left btn-primary">click me</Link>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is not working. same error

Comment: Which react-router-dom version is it? Looks like in v6 you pass state directly as an attribute : <Link to="/zone" state={{ test: 'testing' }}>click me</Link>